# How to Add App Icons for Adobe AIR Mobile App in IntelliJ?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, air

I am creating a mobile app in Intellij using actionscript 3 (and starling). I'm trying to add the app icon images, but I don't see how to do this. In Flash builder you can upload the images in the publish settings dialog box, but there doesn't seem to be a place for this anywhere in Intellij. I also don't see any help in the Intellij help documentation. Is there some secret understood knowledge that you just put them in the src folder and it works or somethinig like that?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "publish settings dialog box"?  I use Flash Builder to build an Android app, and I'm not aware of anything by that name.

Comment: The only dialog box to set app icon I'm aware of is the Flash IDE one.

Answer (score 0):

I voted down your question since it's misleading. Whether using Flash Builder or IntelliJ is irrelevant in that case since underneath it's the Flex/AIR or AIR SDK going on so your question should have been simply about how to set icons since you obviously don't know how to do it with Flash Builder either.

With FB or IntelliJ you set hte icons by editing the project-app.xml that contains all the settings for that app. That file is usually at the root of the project. You'll find there the icons tag (commented out) so you can edit it and put the paths of your icons.